# Homosexuality independent researches

Tags: psychiatry, sexuality, psychology

There are problems in contemporary science, that some researches are influenced by researchers opinion.

(One problem is, that Even in the physics, there is very known problem, that prejudice affects the result of an experiment!

Another problem: it was discussed e.g. in conjunction with economic science, which is in the USA/World scale under reign of only one body of economic opinion and leaving other economic streams being suppressed. It is believed, that this was one of the cause of the world financial crises of 2008.

Still another problem is big pressure to meet political correctness...)

About homosexuality, absolute majority of opinions are polarized..

So please, do you know any researche(s) of homosexuality, what are well balanced or realy independent?

Especially, I would like to learn, what types of homosexuality are there (is some type of homosexuality changeable? some type, what is possible to "heal"? how about combination with heterosexuality? exists some known causes for homosexuality? gene? how about those, who claim, that were "healed from homosexuality?)

If there are more types of homosexuality, what is their prevalence?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. It's best practice to ask focused questions. If you have multiple, it's best to spread them over several posts. As of now, I think the community will vote to close this question because it is too broad. I'm counting at least 8 question marks, that's about 7 too many for a single post.

Comment: First of all, you need to explain what you consider independent researches. The government health organisations are unbiased and have good FAQ’s about sexuality. Right now, I get the feeling that you want us to find studies that say *homosexuality is bad and here’s how to change it*. The few studies that do claim this have fundamental flaws in their reasoning and are not reliable. Consensus of the whole scientific community (which is independent at a large scale) is that homosexuality is perfectly normal, as is any other sexuality, and changing it is not possible and also not a good idea

Comment: [cont’d] because that’s the people’s identity. Similar how one wouldn’t be able to force a change in ethnicity, one can’t force a change in sexuality.

Comment: It depends what one means by "more types of homosexuality". The way you use this term seems to be different than current scholarship. See for example Murray's [Homosexualities](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/H/bo3643465.html). At least "how about combination with heterosexuality?", that's called bisexual(ity). See also "men who have sex with men".

Answer (score 2):

First of all even between quotes you shouldn't use heal about homosexuality.
Then you should first try to learn about sexuality.

**what types of homosexuality are there**

Homosexuality is a thing, one thing. There is now a loooooot of sexualities, you acknowlodge them or not it's up to you, but there is not such a thing as "types of homosexuality".

**how about combination with heterosexuality?**

Are you asking about bisexuality ?

**exists some known causes for homosexuality?**

Homosexuality is "accepted" as something you're born with. Further than this I don't know any research proving there is a gene or a cause for it to happen.

**how about those, who claim, that were "healed from homosexuality?**

I guess you should see it as someone who doesn't like some type of food, but buy forcing himself eating some he actully gets over it.
This being said your sexuality is something quite stronger than your food taste, and going against it often comes with depression and other issues.

**is some type of homosexuality changeable?**

As I said, going against your nature isn't something you should do because it never goes well for you. It always comes with depression, etc...
From your enormous lack of knowledge I guess you're straight, then imagine from now on trying to force yourself to be homosexual ? How hard do you think it would be ? Ho do you think you could deal with it ?